# Limiting game loop to 20 frames per second

Tags: c#, game-engine

See below my main game loop. I am looking for a way to  limit this loop to 20 frames per second

```
    private void renderFrame()
    {

        while (Running)
        {
            game_controls.CheckKeyPress();
            Frame = game_graphics.DrawFrame();

            Panel_Graphics.DrawImage(Frame, 0, 0,320, 320);


            ThreadMonitor.MonitorFPS();

        }

    }
```

Below is the ThreadMonitor class:

```
class Monitor
{

    private int FrameCount;
    private long TickCount;

    private int PanelPosition = 2;
    private Font font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12);

    private Graphics Monitor_Graphics;

    public Monitor(Graphics g)
    {
        AllocConsole();
        Monitor_Graphics = g;
    }

    public void MonitorFPS()
    {
        FrameCount++;

        if (Environment.TickCount >= TickCount + 1000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running: " + FrameCount + "fps");
            FrameCount = 0;
            TickCount = Environment.TickCount;
        }

    }

    #region ShowConsole kernel32.dll

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates Console Window for debugging purposes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> Console </returns>

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    #endregion
```

I want the frames to be generated evenly i do not want the game to stop for half a second.

i am unsure how to acheive this.

Comment: Why not put the DrawFrame call (or DrawImage) on a timer that ticks every 50 ms?

Comment: 1 second = 1000 millisecond. so 1000/20 = 50. you have to wait 50 milliseconds for each frame.

Comment: @o_weisman Thank you i knew there was a simple answer i just had a mental block

Comment: As neolisk said waiting 50ms no matter what wont help you in slow machines or when your render takes some time. You might want to read this about the complexity of game loops: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/651/tips-for-writing-the-main-game-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Waiting 50ms inside the loop will not make your game 20 FPS, it will make your game at most 20 FPS, generally slower, depending on the contents of your loop AND current system/CPU load. Just make sure you understand the difference.

A better way to do this would be waiting required number of milliseconds based on current Environment.TickCount in the **beginning of the loop**. For example, your TickCount is 120ms, and you expect next game tick at 150ms, you need to wait 30 milliseconds, if it's 160ms already, you don't need to wait at all.

Comment: I would recommend using the `Stopwatch` class instead of directly accessing `Environment.TickCount`.  `Stopwatch` has better fallback accuracy for different systems and will generally give you better compatibility.  `Stopwatch` can return elapsed milliseconds too, so the majority of your code can stay the same.